# Merging an attribute over more than one line into one

Tags: r, csv, merge, lines

I have a csv file from facebookscraper, the columns are `comment_author`, `comment_id`, `comment_message`, `likes` etc.

The problem is that the comment_message is sometimes split over more than one line. I tried to merge them by using following code:

```
file <- read.csv("file_name.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
comment <- gsub("[\r\n]", "", file$comment_message)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: you should post a sample excerpt of the data you are working with, but probably the issue is that in `gsub(x, y, z)` the `x` is treated as a regular expression by default, not plain text. you could try `gsub('\r\n', '', file$comment_message, fixed=T`) to replace all instances of `\r\n` with an empty string

Comment: Might need to double escape the `"\\r\\n"`, but as arvi says we can't really tell without seeing sample data.

Comment: @arvi1000 Yes it worked for me, you were right with the issue!